# Are there best practices or conventions to create deterministic vertice and edge ids in AWS Neptune?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am creating a graph database in AWS Neptune for the first time, and I want my edges and vertices to have deterministic id values to make write queries easier (for example, easily being able to get two vertice ids to create an edge between them). I am having trouble finding any good practices or conventions for creating these IDs.

Comment: Is your data brand new, or perhaps coming from an existing database such as a relational one? If so, you may find some of the ideas discussed here of interest https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/tree/master/src/converting-to-graph  IDs can be very useful as they have a uniqueness guarantee. As to what to use for the ID, something meaningful from your domain is the best advice I can really give. For example if you have a lot of people with unique account numbers, perhaps those would make good node IDs.